# Tab-delimited file into dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a tab separated file

How can I input this file into a dictionary?

Comment: Why do you want separate dictionaries for each line?

Comment: To sort them accordingly afterwords. I guess I am very new to python...

Comment: @Mark, Thank you for the suggestions. I will go ahead and follow your advice.

Comment: Well never mind about my previous comment. It turns out that there is a class that does exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import csv

with open(filename) as file_object:
    # skip the first two lines
    file_object.next()
    file_object.next()
    list_of_dicts = list(csv.DictReader(file_object, dialect='excel-tab'))

# list_of_dicts now will contain a list of dictionaries extracted from the file
```

Comment: Instead of iterating and appending, you could just call `list` with the `DictReader` as an argument.

Comment: @notrockstar @Mahmoud Abdelkader
 _"If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference."_ (http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv)

Comment: notrockstar, by definition, a dictionary's ordering will be unordered. if, for some reason, you need an ordered dictionary, let me know, but create another question.

Comment: @ Mahmoud Abdelkader, I do need in exact order as in the file.Is there anyway I can modify the code to read it in exact key order without creating new question? (I know I can do sorting later with lambda function)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `csv` module with its [`DictReader` class](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).

Comment: And an appropriate `Dialect`.

Comment: @notrockstar: If you're sure the first two lines will always be comments, you can call `readline` on the file object twice before you create the `DictReader`.